# Kafka partitioner question, two topics same partition key

Tags: apache-kafka

I have two Kafka topics on the same brokers, both topics use the same UUID as a partitioner, the UUID determines which consumer the records get sent to.  If the same UUIDs are used across both topics does that guarantee the records for both topics arrive at the same consumers, I assume not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the topics have the same number of partitions, then the partitioner logic would map the records to the same partition.

If you're simply subscribing consumers to topics rather than using specific partition assignments, then there are no guarantees which partitions get read